# Evaluating a previously calculated gradient function

Tags: python, performance, session, tensorflow

I am trying to perform optimization using a surrogate model instead of the real function and for that, I need the gradient of my LSTM model with respect to the input. In this case, I have 3 features that vary over time. The LSTM calculates from the initial value of these 3 features the following 100 time steps hence the Jacobian matrix has the shape 100x3x3. It turns out that my code for evaluating the gradient is slower (235 seconds per iteration) than the code that calculates the gradient function (18 seconds per iteration). Would you mind helping me to speed up the gradient evaluation so I can perform optimization using the evaluation function?

The LSTM model and the data can be download from https://gofile.io/?c=azKljF

Code:

```
# multivariate multi-step encoder-decoder lstm for the power usage dataset

from numpy import split, sqrt, linspace, load, savetxt
from numpy import array, zeros, mean,sum, min, max
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras import backend as k
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# split a univariate dataset into train/test sets
def split_dataset(data,n_train,n_test,steps_per_simulation):
    train, test = data[:n_train*steps_per_simulation,:], data[-n_test*steps_per_simulation:,:]
    train = array(split(train, len(train)/steps_per_simulation))
    test = array(split(test, len(test)/steps_per_simulation))
    return train, test

# evaluate forecasts against expected values
def evaluate_forecasts(actual, predicted):
    # calculate an RMSE score for each day
    actual=actual.reshape(actual.shape[0]*actual.shape[1],actual.shape[2])
    predicted=predicted.reshape(predicted.shape[0]*predicted.shape[1],predicted.shape[2])
    rmse=zeros(actual.shape[1]) 
    mse=zeros(actual.shape[1])    
    for j in range(actual.shape[1]):
            # calculate mse
            mse[j] = sum(((actual[:,j]-predicted[:,j])/predicted[:,j])**2)
            # calculate rmse
    rmse = sqrt(mse/len(actual[:,j]))    
    mean_rmse=mean(rmse)
    return mean_rmse, rmse

# summarize scores
def summarize_scores(name, score, scores):
    s_scores = ', '.join(['%.5f' % s for s in scores])
    print('%s: [%.5f] %s' % (name, score, s_scores))

# convert history into inputs and outputs
def to_supervised(train, n_input, n_output):
    # flatten data
    data = train.reshape((train.shape[0]*train.shape[1], train.shape[2]))
    X, y = list(), list()
    in_start = 0
    # step over the entire history one time step at a time
    for _ in range(len(data)):
        # define the end of the input sequence
        in_end = in_start + n_input
        out_end = in_end + n_output
        # ensure we have enough data for this instance
        if out_end <= len(data):
            X.append(data[in_start:in_end, :])
            y.append(data[in_end:out_end, :])
        # move along one time step
        in_start += 1
    return array(X), array(y)

# train the model
def build_model(train, n_input, n_feat, n_output):
    # prepare data
    train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train, n_input,n_output)
    # define parameters
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = True, 4, 7*n_output
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]
    # reshape output into [samples, timesteps, features]
    train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[1], train_y.shape[2]))
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
    model.add(LSTM(10, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_feat)))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    # fit network
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,shuffle='true')
    return model

# evaluate a single model
def build(train, n_input,n_output,n_feat):
    # fit model
    model = build_model(train, n_input,n_feat,n_output)
    history = [x for x in train]
    return model, history

def predict(model,test,n_input,n_feat):  
    # walk-forward validation over each week
    data = array(test)
    data = data.reshape((data.shape[0]*data.shape[1], data.shape[2]))
    predictions = list()
    for i in range(test.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,test.shape[1]):
            input_x=test[i,j:j+n_input,:].reshape(1,n_input,n_feat)
            yhat = model.predict(input_x, verbose=0)
            yhat = yhat[0]
            predictions.append(yhat[0,:])
    predictions = array(predictions).reshape(test.shape)
    return predictions


def predict100(model,test2,n_input,n_output,n_feat):  
    predictions2 = zeros((test2.shape[0],n_input+n_output,n_feat))
    predictions2[:,:n_input,:]=test2[:,:n_input,:]
    for i in range(test2.shape[0]):
            input_x=test2[i,:n_input,:].reshape(1,n_input,n_feat)
            yhat = model.predict(input_x, verbose=0)
            yhat = yhat[0:n_output,:].reshape(yhat.shape[1],yhat.shape[2])
            predictions2[i,n_input:,:]=yhat
    return predictions2


def evaluate_model(test, predictions):
    score, scores = evaluate_forecasts(test, predictions)
    return score, scores

def normalize(x0,data):
    Norm_dataset=zeros(x0.shape)
    n_feat=x0.shape[-1]
    for i in range(0,n_feat):
        Norm_dataset[:,i]=(x0[:,i]-min(data[:,i]))/(max(data[:,i])-min(data[:,i]))
    return Norm_dataset

def unnormalize(x0,data):
    Unnorm_dataset=zeros(x0.shape)
    n_feat=x0.shape[-1]
    for i in range(0,n_feat):
        Unnorm_dataset[:,i]=x0[:,i]*(max(data[:,i])-min(data[:,i]))+min(data[:,i])
    return Unnorm_dataset
#
def jacobian_tensorflow(model,x0,n_feat,n_output,sess):
    jacobian_matrix = []
    for i in range(n_output):
        print('Calculating dx'+str(i+1)+'/dx0')
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        for m in range(n_feat):
        # We iterate over the M elements of the output vector
            start_time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
            grad_func = tf.gradients(model.output[:,i,m], model.input)
            end_time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
            diff1 = (end_time1 - start_time1).total_seconds()
            print('Calculating Jacobian function time=',diff1)
            start_time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
            gradients = sess.run(grad_func, feed_dict={model.input: x0})
            end_time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
            diff2 = (end_time2 - start_time2).total_seconds()
            print('Evaluating Jacobian time=',diff2)
            jacobian_matrix.append(gradients[0][0,:])  
        end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        diff = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
        print('Total time=',diff)
    return array(jacobian_matrix)

def get_grad_func(model,n_feat,n_output):
    grad_func1=[]
    grad_func2=[]
    grad_func3=[]
    grad_func=[]
    for i in range(n_output):
        print('Calculating dx'+str(i+1)+'/dx0')
        grad_func1.append(tf.gradients(model.output[:,i,0], model.input))
        grad_func2.append(tf.gradients(model.output[:,i,1], model.input))
        grad_func3.append(tf.gradients(model.output[:,i,2], model.input))   
    grad_func1= tf.reshape(grad_func1,[n_output,1,n_feat])    
    output1=tf.stack(grad_func1)   
    grad_func2= tf.reshape(grad_func2,[n_output,1,n_feat])       
    output2=tf.stack(grad_func2) 
    grad_func3= tf.reshape(grad_func3,[n_output,1,n_feat])  
    output3=tf.stack(grad_func3) 
    grad_func.append(output1)
    grad_func.append(output2)
    grad_func.append(output3)
    return grad_func

def eval_grad(model,x0,n_feat,n_output,sess,grad_func):
    jacobian_matrix = []
    for i in range(n_output):
        print('Evaluating dx'+str(i+1)+'/dx0')
        for n in range(n_feat):
            for m in range(n_feat):
                gradients = sess.run(grad_func[n][i,:,m], feed_dict={model.input: x0})
                jacobian_matrix.append(gradients)        
    J_matrix=zeros((n_output,n_feat,n_feat))
    count=0
    for i in range(n_output):
        for j in range(n_feat):
            J_matrix[i,j,:]=jacobian_matrix[count:count+n_feat]
            count=count+n_feat
    return J_matrix


# load the new file

L3D=load('lorenz-3d.npy')
original_dataset=L3D[:,:,:].reshape(L3D.shape[0]*L3D.shape[1],L3D.shape[2])


n_input=1
n_output=100
steps_per_simulation=501
n_train=9970
n_test=30


dataset = normalize(original_dataset,original_dataset)
n_feat=dataset.shape[1]

# split into train and test
train, test = split_dataset(dataset,n_train,n_test,steps_per_simulation)

# load json and create model
json_file = open('1_input_100_output_9970training.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
model.load_weights("1_input_100_output_9970training.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

x0=dataset[0,:].reshape(1,n_input,n_feat)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#I replaced n_output =100 by n_output=5 so the code runs faster

grad_func=get_grad_func(model,n_feat,5)

J=eval_grad(model,x0,n_feat,5,sess,grad_func)

savetxt('Jacobian',J.reshape(J.shape[0],J.shape[2]))

sess.close()
```

Comment: Use numpy. n-dimensional numerics are simply not feasible in bare Python.

Comment: Per your question, please do provide `data and full code`, this question will quickly get closed otherwise.